# Does bottom watering basil work?

Tags: watering, basil, drainage

I have a couple basil plants growing in pots. Normally I'm told that I should water it from the top and let it drain fully through the holes on the bottom of the pot. Can I bottom water these plants instead (submerge the pots in a couple inches of water) rather than doing it the normal way?

Two of the pots have roots sticking through the drainage holes, but one pot contains recently propagated basil plants whose roots haven't reached the drainage holes. Will bottom watering still work in this case?

Lastly, when bottom watering an average size pot for indoor growing, about how long should it take?